# Kommasetzung bei Aufzählung mit "wie"

Tags: comma, list

Welche der folgenden Varianten hat eine richtige Kommasetzung?

> "Es bietet mir die Möglichkeit, Dinge, wie Physik, Biologie und andere Künste, zu lernen."
>
> "Es bietet mir die Möglichkeit, Dinge wie Physik, Biologie und andere Künste zu lernen."
>
> "Es bietet mir die Möglichkeit, Dinge, wie Physik, Biologie und andere Künste zu lernen."

Answer (score 8):

[Paragraph §78.2](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf78) ist dein Freund. Beispiele, die mit *wie* eingeleitet sind, **können** mit einem Komma abgetrennt werden.
Setzt du jedoch ein Komma, so muss **vor und nach** dem Einschub ein Komma gesetzt werden.

Folglich sind die ersten beiden gleichermaßen korrekt, während der dritte Satz fehlerhaft ist.

Comment: Version 2 impliziert einen *bestimmenden* Vergleich: es gibt viele Dinge, aber die Lernmöglichkeit bezieht sich auf Physik, Biologie etc. (also Wissenschaften), nicht einfach auf beliebige Dinge. Version 1 impliziert dagegen einen *erläuternden* Vergleich, so als ob tatsächlich die Möglichkeit bestünde, alles und jedes zu lernen, und als ob Physik, Biologie etc. typische Vertreter von "Dingen" seien. Das kommt mir seh unwahrscheinlich vor, deshalb ist Version 1 für mich viel weniger akzeptabel.

Comment: @KilianFoth Den Unterschied sehe ich nicht. De facto sehe ich gar keinen Unterschied.

Comment: @KilianFoth Da sich ein Komma (hier) nicht in der gesprochenen Sprache niederschlägt, weigere ich mich, anzuerkennen, dass das Komma einen Bedeutungsunterschied erzeugen würde.

Answer (score 0):

Gemäß § 78 des amtlichen Regelwerks gilt (vgl. [Regeln redigiert 2018](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf)):

> Oft liegt es im Ermessen des Schreibenden, ob er etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen will oder nicht.
>
> ---
>
> Dies betrifft
>   
>   ...
>   
>   (2) Gefüge mit *wie* (zu *wie* in Vergleichen siehe § 74 E3):
>   
>   *Ihre Ausgaben(,) wie Fahrt- und Übernachtungskosten(,) werden Ihnen ersetzt.*

Häufig wird diese Regel insofern fehlinterpretiert, als dass viele Schreiber vermeinen, man könnte das Komma nach Belieben setzen. Das stimmt so nicht, denn es hängt davon ab, ob wir es mit einem Vergleich bzw. einer vergleichsartigen Erläuterung oder doch mit einer eingeschobenen Erläuterung bzw. einem angefügten Beispiel zu tun haben.

#### Vergleich oder vergleichsartige Erläuterung

Sehen wir uns die folgenden Sätze an:

> - Wörter wie Haus, Ente oder Hubschrauber werden großgeschrieben.
> - Hier wachsen nur Getreidesorten wie Hafer, Roggen oder Weizen.

Hierbei handelt es sich um einen Vergleich oder eine vergleichsartige Erläuterung, nicht aber um bloße Einschübe! Ohne die Erläuterungen ergäben die Sätze inhaltlich keinen Sinn:

> - <s>Wörter werden großgeschrieben.</s>
> - <s>Hier wachsen nur Getreidesorten.</s>

#### Eingeschobene Erläuterung oder angefügtes Beispiel

Anders sieht es aus, wenn wir es mit echten Einschüben oder angefügten Beispielen zu tun haben:

> - Substantive, *wie Haus, Ente und Hubschrauber*, werden großgeschrieben.
> - Hier wachsen verschiedene Getreidesorten, *wie zum Beispiel Hafer, Roggen und Weizen*.

Die Sätze bleiben auch ohne die Einschübe richtig:

> - Substantive werden großgeschrieben.
> - Hier wachsen verschiedene Getreidesorten.

#### Beispielsatz aus dem Regelwerk

> Ihre Ausgaben(,) wie Fahrt- und Übernachtungskosten(,) werden Ihnen ersetzt.

Bei diesem Beispielsatz aus dem Regelwerk obliegt es tatsächlich dem Schreibenden, wie er ihn interpretiert. Interpretiert man die Wortfolge *wie Fahrt- und Übernachtungskosten* als einen beispielgebenden Einschub in den Satz

> Ihre Ausgaben werden Ihnen ersetzt.

dann muss dieser Einschub durch Kommas abgetrennt werden. Interpretiert man die Wortfolge hingegen als vergleichende Erläuterung, durch die andere Arten von Ausgaben ausgeschlossen werden, dann darf kein Komma stehen. *Nach Ermessen* heißt hier also keinesfalls *nach Lust und Laune*, sondern richtet sich nach dem, was ausgesagt werden soll.

#### Beispielsätze aus der Frage

Schauen wir uns nun den Satz

> - Es bietet mir die Möglichkeit, Dinge wie Physik, Biologie und andere Künste zu lernen.

genauer an. Die Wortfolge *wie Physik, Biologie und andere Künste* ist hier kein Einschub von Beispielen, sondern eine vergleichsartige Erläuterung, die beschreibt, um welche Art von Dingen es sich handelt. Der Zusatz *und andere Künste* sagt ja schon, dass nicht alle Dinge, sondern Künste gemeint sind. Der Satz

> - <s>Es bietet mir die Möglichkeit, Dinge zu lernen.</s>

ist zwar grammatisch korrekt, ergibt aber inhaltlich keinen Sinn, weil die nähere Erläuterung fehlt.